# How to use 3rd party libraries in GWT which use "document"

Tags: gwt

I want to use a 3rd party JS library from within GWT. I know that you can use GWT JSNI - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

As explained in that documentation, you need to use `$doc` instead of `document`. How do you use 3rd party libraries which are using `document`?

This is not a duplicate, as it is asking specifically about the key word `document` being used in 3rd party libraries, and not generally how to use JS in GWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the JS library is injected to the main html page, and not in the gwt iframe. Then, you can be sure that `window` and `document` mean what you expect them to mean.

This can be done by simply creating the `<script>` tag in the html file as one normally might do, or if using the `ScriptInjector.fromUrl` method, calling `.setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)` on it.

Then, in your JSNI (please don't write JSNI, use JsInterop instead), reference the library with a `$wnd` prefix. In JsInterop, just model the objects that you intend to interact with, and mark the namespace correctly, the compiler will insert `$wnd` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

With Js Interop you can write an interface to your js library and then use it from GWT as it was Java.

Chance is someone already wrote an interface for you (if it's a common lib).

Here more info on Interop: http://www.luigibifulco.it/blog/en/blog/gwt-2-8-0-jsinterop